# Get blob content from file using wildcard

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Example:

> Blob: container/folder/myfile123.txt [where 123 is dynamic]

I am trying to get the content of an Azure blob file by using a wildcard for the extension since it can be different, but always the same leading (like `myfile`) and ending extension (like `.txt`).  I've tested using things like `myfile*.txt` or `myfile?.txt` but no success when specifying the path.

For getting a wildcard file using the *Get blob content* tool in logic apps, how can I get a file by a leading name and ending extension but any possible combination between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the exact name of the file.

What you can do is to get a list of all blobs in the container. Then loop over that list getting each individual file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "List blobs" connector and then the "Filter array" collections connector to get the wildcard functionality via the "contains"-operator. Then just use the "Get blob using path" and type in the expression: body('Filter_array')[0]['name']

Or in code view:
"path": "/my_catalogue/@{body('Filter_array')[0]['name']}"

to get the first filename that matches your wildcard.

[image]